# Can't change CC in go env

Tags: visual-studio, go, gcc, clang

I can't change the CC in my go env. I use Windows 10 with Cmder set to bash as admin. I am trying to build and run a go program with `go get github.com/icexin/gocraft` but I keep getting the same error `cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%`. I don't have any third party gcc compilers installed. This is because I only have a lot of C and C++ tools installed with Visual Studio and I don't want to clutter up my path with multiple build tools and confuse any of the C dev tools that I use which rely on Visual Studio's clang version. The path to my Visual Studio clang tool that is a perfectly adequate substitute for a third party gcc (as typed into Cmder) is `/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang-cl.exe`. I tried running:
`export CC=/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang-cl.exe`,
`export CC=/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang-cl.exe`,
`export CC=C:\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin\clang-cl.exe`,

none of which worked. How do I change gcc to my Visual Studio clang path? Or change the go env CC variable?

**EDIT**
I figured out that the problem is that the `go env CC` declaration cuts off after `C:\Program`. I set the `CC` in the Windows Environment Variables, the `set` command, and the `export` command and `go env CC` always cuts off after `C:\Program` no matter how I input the file path.

**EDIT 2**
Look I'm no the only one with this issue:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41400

Comment: Cgo doesn't fully support llvm, and I believe mingw is the only option for windows. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been unable to get any solution to work. This is because this is a know issue with Go detailed here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41400. Apparently the CC variable will split at the first space in go env, even if you add a `\` before the space. Even if I was able to get this to work however, the clang version that ships with Visual Studio doesn't actually work for cgo.

Answer (score 2):

Use [go env](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Print_Go_environment_information) to inspect Go environment variables - and the `-w` flag to make a change persistent:

```
# go env -w "CC=clang-cl.exe"

# go env CC

clang-cl.exe
```

Comment: Now I get `cgo: exec clang-cl.exe: exec: "clang-cl.exe": executable file not found in %PATH%` is there any way to get clang-cl.exe into an executable?